# FlatList horizontal onViewableItemsChanged not firing if I use getItemLayout

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have horizontal FlatList and try to get visible item with `onViewableItemsChanged`
event and if I use `getItemLayout` props. event not firing on Android if its horizontal.iOS working well.
Here is  demo .if you remove `horizontal` or `getItemLayout` props. working fine. but I also need `getItemLayout`
https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/flatlist-getitemlayout

Answer (score 0):

this looks like it's happening because you're setting `waitForInteraction: true`. When the list is vertical, scrolling registers an interaction from the vertical scroll, calling the callback. In order to trigger the interaction when the list is vertical, you have to scroll horizontally on the list.

To fix you can set `waitForInteraction` to false

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this is you have to use any parameter for determining the item is on visible on screen or not.

If you are using the `viewabilityConfig` and `getItemLayout` then you might get this problem, you can remove the `viewabililtyConfig` then it will work.